# Javascript regex remove trailing zeroes after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I know this has been asked many times and I did find a solution, `value.replace(/^([\d,]+)$|^([\d,]+)\.0*$|^([\d,]+\.[0-9]*?)0*$/, "$1$2$3")`.

But... I'm no regex expert so I'm just curious as to why this doesn't work `/[\.0]+$/`... 10 should return 10 but I just can't figure out how to exclude whole numbers that end with 0s.

1.7500, 1.1010, 1.0000, 10

1.75, 1.101, 1, 1

Comment: `/[\.0]+$/` does not require the input to have a decimal point. You need to require it.

Comment: @trincot I thought by not using `?` that the decimal was required?

Comment: But `[\.0]` leaves the choice to match with either `.` or with `0`. So if every time (of the repeated `+`) it is an `0`, it will still match -- without ever having matched a dot.

Comment: @trincot so following your recommendations I'm able to capture the group after the decimal with this `(?<=\.)` but can't do anything with the group, like test if it ends with 0s. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might shorten the pattern to match either a dot with only zeroes, or use a non greedy match for the digits with a capture group and match optional trailing zeroes.

If you want to match digits and comma's the first `\d+` can also be `[\d,]+` as you already have in your pattern.

If there should be at least a single digit after the dot, then the quantifier can be a plus `.\d+?`

```
^(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*?)0+)$
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RBONGC/1).

```js
[
  "1.7500",
  "1.1010",
  "1.0000",
  "10"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(/^(\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*?)0+)$/, "$1$2"))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that simplifies the solution I found...